# Is there a new problem with mathrsfs?

Tags: fonts, miktex

A problem arose after updating today, and I traced it to the package mathrsfs.  This file works fine with `\usepackage{mathrsfs}`commented out, but fails when `\usepackage{mathrsfs}` is put back in

```
\documentclass{amsart}
%\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\begin{document}
a
\end{document}
```

To be precise I am using MiKTeX Revision 2.9.6809, and running PDFTeXify on the file.

When I try it with mathrsfs it generates the following error messages, and it produces no PDF:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.6880 64-bit)
The top-level auxiliary file: What.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file What.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file What.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file What.aux
(There were 3 error messages)


Command Line:   pdflatex.exe --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=-1 "What.tex"
Startup Folder: C:\Users\User\Documents\TeX_Files\Cohomology_foundations

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6880 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(What.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amscls\amsart.cls"
Document Class: amsart 2017/10/31 v2.20.4
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsmath.sty"
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amstext.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsgen.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsbsy.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsopn.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsa.fd")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\amsfonts.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\jknappen\mathrsfs.sty") (What.aux)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsa.fd")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsb.fd")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\jknappen\ursfs.fd")
! Font U/rsfs/m/n/8=rsfs10 at 8.0pt not loadable: Bad metric (TFM) file.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.4 \begin{document}

? 

Process has been terminated ...
```

My MiKTeX Console says jknappen is still installed, and the jknappen folder has mathrsfs in it. Can someone help me regain the use of that package?

Comment: No problem with MikTeX on Ubuntu.  Is your system up-to-date? https://miktex.org/howto/update-miktex

Comment: No problem with the latest version of MikTeX on windows 10

Comment: Works fine here. The tfm is normally created automatically in `...\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts\tfm\public\rsfs\rsfs10.tfm`. If there is a tfm delete or rename it and try again.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer  Now I see!  The log tells me Bad metric (TFM) file.  But I did not know what that meant.